# What to do with answer on duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions

Sometimes a question is answered (with the right solution) before it is marked as a duplicate.

After it is marked as duplicate:

- Should it be upvoted?
- Does the OP have to mark it as the solution?
- Does the answerer have to delete it?

Comment: Personally, if the duplicate is _really_ obvious, I'm tempted to downvote the answer if it's a clear case of farming rep. (High rep user, question that gets asked multiple times per day)

Comment: Since SO does not add the incentive - *read:* **only badges down the line and no rep points** to helpful *duplicate* flags. I think each answer has to be judged based on whether or not it's a good answer for the question regardless of the fact that the question might be a duplicate. I disagree with the idea of downvoting a good answer just because the question is duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

> Should it be upvoted?

Well, is it useful?  If it doesn't add anything that the dupe doesn't cover then I would say no.

> Does the OP have to mark it as the solution?

The OP never has to accept an answer.  They can if they want to but it's up to them

> Does the answerer have to delete it?

No, it does not have to be deleted.  Typically if the question is an obvious dupe then I vote to delete the question (which also deletes the answer) as it doesn't add anything to the site.

---

Do note that if the dupe is not so obvious, and the new questions adds another way to find the duplicate (adds more search terms) then there is no reason to get rid of it.  It will act as a sign post and the more good sign posts we have the easier time people should have finding the correct information.

One thing I do like to do if the dupe is really obvious is comment to the answerer and let them know that instead of answering they should flag/vote to close.  I feel that answerers should try and find a dupe target before answering as we don't want to blindly duplicate content.

Comment: I asked the question because I had this case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45082624/4498831

Comment: @Boiethios I really can't weigh in on that specific example as it is outside my domain but it does look like it would be a useful sign post.